# permission in AndroidManfest wonl't work

Tags: java, android

I add this two line into AndroidManfest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

but when I want to install my app in my own phone (not ADB) it won't show permission to me and say this app have no access or ... to anything.

my app is downloading some web content and I need internet permission for that.
what's the problem?

Comment: it won't show permission to me and say this app have no acces or ... to anything => do you know about INTERNET permission? Have you tried building a demo app and checking whether it's asking!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)

Comment: @PareshMayani i'm new in android , my app work fine in ADB , i did not get it your meant about demo app.

Comment: @Zoe it says there if you use marshmallow , but i use API 14 !

Comment: @ali you don't add any details about the system you use, target and compile version or any code at all. You don't even add the actual stacktrace to the question. Create an MCVE and check the stack overflow how to ask guide. In its current state, it's off-topic

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                //Show Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,false)) {
                //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        sentToSettings = true;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else {
                //just request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,true);
            editor.commit();


        } else {
            //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }
```